# C# Encode.<format>.GetBytes() returning different data to that input

Tags: c#, encode

From the docs, Encode should provide a way to convert bytes to a string and back again. However, this test case gives very different results after the decode. The input data 'bytes' is 6 elements, but the output data 'outputData' is 17 elements. Why is this?

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 24, 48, 49, 127, 250, 255, 1 };

    char[] charData = Encoding.UTF7.GetChars(bytes);
    byte[] outputData = Encoding.UTF7.GetBytes(charData);
```

Comment: You use text encodings when you have *arbitrary* sets of characters and need to control their *byte* representations. Not for taking an *arbitrary* set of bytes and turning them into characters. You have a set of bytes that a UTF-7 encoding of characters would *never produce*. It's not surprising that you can't round trip them when trying to use it the wrong way around.

Comment: If you have an *arbitrary* set of bytes and need to round-trip them via strings, you should be looking for something that is designed to work that way around - e.g. Base-64 encoding.

Comment: [UTF7Encoding does not provide error detection. When invalid bytes are encountered, UTF7Encoding generally emits the invalid bytes........](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf7encoding.getchars?view=netframework-4.8), decoding with `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charData);` shows this.

Answer (score 2):

From Damien_The_Unbeliever's suggestion, found Convert instead

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 24, 48, 49, 127, 250, 255, 1 };

    // encode
    string byteString = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    byte[] byteList = Convert.FromBase64String(byteString);
```